# section blog joomla with category titles

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

Hi I have a section blog in joomla

section:
animal

categories:
dog
cat
horse

output looks like this:

```
dog
dog 1
-----
dog
dog 2
-----
cat
cat 1
-----
dog
dog 3
-----
horse
horse 1
-----
```

But I want this output: (sorted on the categories and add them as a title)

```
dogs:

dog 1
-----
dog 2
-----
dog 3
------

cats:

cat 1
-----

horses:

horse 1
-----
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.theartofjoomla.com/home/6-layouts/38-layout-override-making-a-joomla-section-look-like-a-book-contents.html

This is the answer, great article!